# Iphone WebApp Footer Toolbar

Tags: android, iphone, html, mobile, iphone-standalone-web-app

I'm creating a web App for mobile devices, but i have an issue with the footer toolbar in iphone, i just want to hide or remove it but i trying without results.

I was reading in apple support for use some metatags like that:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
```

But the toolbar is always showing up...

Is there any way to hide it and make a "Looks like" native application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add your site/web app in device home screen. The metatags provided from Apple works only if you have a link from home screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
#menu
{
    text-align:center;
    margin-top: 20px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#000;
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
}
```

and then call it in your division !
If it is a web app.

Comment: Try [this](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page)
Or [this](http://www.wickham43.net/headerfooterfix.php)

Comment: Thanks for the comments, maybe there is a misunderstanding, i just want to remove the footer toolbar in the mobile client, i mean the defaults browser footer toolbar, not add some new menu o something like that!

Comment: does [this](http://doctyper.com/archives/200808/fixed-positioning-on-mobile-safari/) help ?

Comment: yes, but id dont fix my problem, i mean, i want to remove the  footer, not create a new one.